# Pickle can't be load for Pascal VOC pickle dataset

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, pickle, semantic-segmentation

I'm trying to load Pascal VOC dataset from Stanford website [here](http://www.ais.uni-bonn.de/deep_learning/downloads.html). Also trying to implement a code from [Semantic Image Segmentation on Pascal VOC Pystruct blog](http://pystruct.github.io/auto_examples/image_segmentation.html). But I'm getting UnicodeDecodeError when I tried to load the pickle file. I tried below code so far:

```
import numpy as np
try:
    import cPickle as pickle
except ImportError:
    import pickle

from pystruct import learners
import pystruct.models as crfs
from pystruct.utils import SaveLogger

data_train = pickle.load(open("trainingData/data_train.pickle"))
C = 0.01
```

And I got this errror:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mypath/PycharmProjects/semantic_segmentation_ex/ex1.py", line 11, in <module>
    data_train = pickle.load(open("trainingData/data_train.pickle"))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
    return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I couldn't find any same problem and solution. How do I get this to work?

Comment: Typically, Pickle files should be opened in the binary mode: `open("trainingData/data_train.pickle","rb")`.

Comment: Tried but still I got same error

Comment: You may want to add a `encoding='latin-1'` as an argument.

Comment: Where should I add this encoding argument ?

Comment: `pickle.load(open("trainingData/data_train.pickle", 'wb', encoding='latin-1'))`

Comment: Unfortunately! "binary mode doesn't take an encoding argument"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of my friend told me the reason. Serialized object is a python2 object, so if you load with Python2, it's opening directly without any problem.

But If you would like to load with Python3, you need to add encoding parameters to pickle not into open function. Here is sample code:

```
import numpy as np

try:
    import cPickle as pickle
except ImportError:
    import pickle


with open('data_train.pickle', 'rb') as f:
    # If you use Python 3 needs a parameter as encoding='bytes'
    # Otherwise, you shouldn't add encoding parameters in Python 2
    data_train = pickle.load(f, encoding='bytes')


print("Finished loading data!")
print(data_train.keys())
```

Special thanks to @ahmet-sezgin-duran